# SectionList - Update particular row data

Tags: react-native

I am rendering 100s of data(Feeds) using SectionList , user can like and share and the particular row has be updated accordingly.  I know I can do using `extraData`. But I am not sure how exactly its gonna work out as I am rendering three sections and at third feeds are getting rendered.  Is there any way to just update that row instead rendering again?

Right now I am setting as

```
this.actionInProgress = false
*****
extraData = {[this.actionInProgress]}
```

Whenever user clicks on like I update actionInProgress and renders current data.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why don't you want to render again?

Comment: From performance point. In ListView I could have achieved this using immutable objects but it does not happen here